# Calculo de desconto em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer a soma de produtos e dar 10% de desconto no valor total dos produtos, segue o código abaixo.

```
let produtos1 = 150.00
let produtos2 = 100.00
let produtos3 = 228.00

soma = produtos1 + produtos2 + produtos3

if (soma >= 200) {
  console.log('voce acaba de ganha um desconto de 10%')
  console.log('novo subtotal '+ desconto)
} else {
  console.log('adicione mais produtos para ganha o desconto')
}
```

Comment: let desconto = soma-(soma*.1);

Comment: Sei que já tem um comentário e uma resposta te dando o caminho, mas não posso deixar de comentar: esse não é um problema de programação, e sim de matemática. Acredito que conseguiria resolver sozinho caso fizesse antes um exercício no papel, sem pensar em código, só na matemática. Encare isso como um conselho, se não conseguir fazer esse tipo de operação matemática sozinho, vai ser complicado dominar a lógica de programação.

Comment: é a pandemia que não deixa ir pra aulas de matematica

Answer (score 2):

Para "descontar" 10% de um valor, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
desconto = valor * 0.1; // 10% do valor
descontado = valor - desconto; // 90% do valor (10% de desconto)
```

Ou simplesmente calcule o complemento do que você quer descontar. No caso, como quer descontar 10%, basta calcular 90% do preço. Temos, então:

```
descontado = valor * 0.9; // 90% do valor (10% de desconto)
```

Assim:

```js
let produtos1 = 150;
let produtos2 = 100;
let produtos3 = 228;
 
let soma = produtos1 + produtos2 + produtos3;

if (soma >= 200) {
  let descontado = soma * 0.9;
  
  console.log('voce acaba de ganha um desconto de 10%');
  console.log('total sem desconto:', soma);
  console.log('você pagará:', descontado);
} else {
  console.log('adicione mais produtos para ganha o desconto');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function ganharDesconto(...products) {
  const total = products.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

  if (total > 200) {    
    return `Você recebeu desconto e o valor ficou: ${total * 0.9}`
  }

  console.log('Adicione mais produtos para ganhar desconto.')
}
```

- ganharDesconto(100, 101) // "Você recebeu desconto e o valor ficou: 180.9"
- ganharDesconto(10, 20, 30, 40) // "Adicione mais produtos para ganhar desconto."